# Use a Grafana discrete panel to monitor a tag (InfluxDB)

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have the device state in the form of a tag and not as a field. I understand how a discrete panel can be used to monitor a field. Different field values will populate with time.

But, what I have is a constant field value which is always 1 when there is a datapoint. And the health is monitored as a tag (3 values possible, represented by strings).

I would like to know if I can somehow use the discrete panel for this tag to get a similar result when we do it with a field.